# Using a spline to clip an image?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, spline

I have an image of a user's face in a canvas element. I want them to be able to draw around it to cut it out. I have successfully used a Splice to draw a nice smooth curve around their face (the splice points array increases by one with each mouse click, getting longer and longer).

But I am unsure how to actually use this Spline to clip the image. I can access the points array using the mySpline.allPoints array, and then draw my own clipping path, but this produces a very linear shape, without all the nice Spline calculated curves.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but here is the code of how the spline is drawn:

```
     drawFunc: function(canvas) {
        var points = this.getPoints(), length = points.length, context = canvas.getContext(), tension = this.getTension();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

        // tension
        if(tension !== 0 && length > 2) {
            var ap = this.allPoints, len = ap.length;
            context.quadraticCurveTo(ap[0].x, ap[0].y, ap[1].x, ap[1].y);

            var n = 2;
            while(n < len - 1) {
                context.bezierCurveTo(ap[n].x, ap[n++].y, ap[n].x, ap[n++].y, ap[n].x, ap[n++].y);
            }

            context.quadraticCurveTo(ap[len - 1].x, ap[len - 1].y, points[length - 1].x, points[length - 1].y);

        }
        // no tension
        else {
            for(var n = 1; n < length; n++) {
                var point = points[n];
                context.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            }
        }

        canvas.stroke(this);
    },
```

It uses quadraticCurveTo and bezierCurveTo to draw the curves, given the curve's points.

Comment: so essentially, you need your clipping path to be a bezier/quadratic curve between all of it's points. If the clipping path doesn't allow for curves, you have to calculate intermediate points along the curve and make those part of your clipping path.

Comment: Thanks EliteOctagon. This is the best solution I came up with myself. When it comes to doing the actual clipping, I just grab the spline (and all its points - it seems to generate some "in between" points somehow, which are needed). Then I just use the code as above to manually draw a clipping path again. Its a shame because I am duplicating code, but it works :)

Comment: any chance you could show some of the code in a jsfiddle? I'd love to see the clipping curve functionality in action.

Comment: Some duplicated code doesn't hurt, it would be different if you had your entire program with duplications all over the place.

Comment: No problem. Too hard to put in a jsfiddle, so I've uploaded my work in progress to my domain.

 -- Hit "start" to load the image
 -- Hit "Start Clip Path" and click around the face to draw points
 -- Hit "Complete Clip Path" to finalize. Now you can drag and edit points
 -- Hit "clip" to clip the image

http://richsavage.co.uk/labs/canvas_clipping/